# How do I make the php script work as a superuser

Tags: php, permissions, cron

I've assumed that if my php script has permissions set to root, the script would be able to execute commands as a root user. But apparently, it's not the case. I noticed that I cannot write anything outside of www and when I want to write a text file at /test.txt, it won't create a file because of permissions at / saying that non-root users only can access but not create or delete but the script itself has the root permission. If I change permissions at / then it works fine. Why can't my php script, set to have root permissions, write to the / directory?

And what can I do to enable the php script to be executed as a superuser?

I want to use the exec() and I cannot seem to get it to work. I want to be able to create a crontab and it doesn't work. I wrote a code like this:

```
   exec("crontab -l > test.txt; echo '* * * * * echo hi! > /root/Desktop/hi.txt'>> test.txt; crontab test.txt");
```

But it won't work. If I copy the string into terminal, it works as expected.

Comment: You need to add platform data: apache? nginx? cgi/fastcgi/module? Is the script even run through a web server (I assume given that it's in www) or is it a command line (CLI)?

Comment: As a suggestion, don't make edits that ask separate questions.  For running apache as root, just google - basics are to update the user and group in your http.conf file and restart.  As for the crontab question, it's going to list the cron of the current user that apache is running as, probably fail to write hi.txt the desktop due to permissions, and then import test.txt, which is probably empty.  Remember, each user has their own crontab.

Comment: actually, it's more about accessing the outside www directory. The crontab works fine if I run it in terminal. if I run php, a new file is never created. So I don't think it's my php... just need to know how I can have PHP script execute as a root.

Comment: BTW, I have set all my www files to have root permissions and it still doesn't do a thing outside of www if the other directories ahve different permissions although having a root permission means I override any permissions in any directories, right?

Comment: First off, permissions are generally about what can access it, not how it runs.  Directory permissions do not cascade to the contents.  Like I said, google for running apache as root, and you'll find plenty of results describing how to modify the http.conf and restart apache (as well as saying this is a bad idea)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the permissions on the script file itself does not affect who the script is run as.  it affects who can access the script.

To run the script as root, it depends on the context.  Are you running it in a web server or is this a CLI script?  If the later, then you must run it while logged in as the root user or with the sudo command.  If its in a web-server as apache, then you must configure apache to run as as root but this is highly discouraged as it opens up a lot of security risks.

Comment: And for completeness, if you're running it from the command line and have sudo permissions, you can run it using `sudo`.  Of course, the better option is to handle permissions properly, and have it generate it's output to somewhere sane, rather than the root of the file system.

Comment: He can't set a sticky bit on the permissions instead of using sudo?

Comment: how do I set Apache to run as root? Security's not an issue since it is not for Internet  (only intranet)

Comment: You should still be mindful of security.  A better approach would be to grant write permissions to the necessary folders to the user Apache is running as.  The user Apache is running as is set in its config file.  See Apache's documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions/ownership of a script have no bearing on which user that script runs as. It will run as whichever user executes it, assuming it has permission to do so. *Sometimes* you can use the setuid 'sticky bit' permission to do things like this, but most systems do not allow it, and the least offensive term I can think of to describe allowing it is "inadvisable".

> I noticed that I cannot write anything outside of www

Because apache is configured properly. Ideally it will run as a non-root users [usually www] and any scripts will run as that user as well. Instead of telling you how to configure apache to be less secure why not just grant the apache user access to the file/directory that you want to access/modify?

Comment: How do I grant the apache user access to those directories that i want to modify? I am pretty clueless.

Comment: I did the chmod to set all my php scripts to have root permissions but it still doesn't work. It cannot execute or write files on a desktop. If I copy the string from exec() into terminal, it works fine.